# $resource with custom action and url doesn't work

Tags: rest, angularjs, angular-resource

I would like to add the $update method to the Todo object.
Here's my code:

```
destinataire_id=10
var Todo = $resource('todosjson?destinataire_id=:destinataire_id', 
    {},
    {"update":
        {
            method:'PUT',
            url:'todosjson/:id',
            params:{'id':'@id'}
        }
    }
    );

$scope.todos = Todo.query({destinataire_id:id})

$scope.updateStatus= function (todo) {
    console.log(todo)
    todo.$update()
}
```

When I look into the console, I get PUT requests on todosjson?destinataire_id=?id=81

What's the issue ?